# wxwidgets directories not recognized by gcc compiler

Tags: gcc, wxwidgets

I am attempting to add a directory to include in gcc's search for c++ header files. Why? Because wxwidgets seems to refuse to install the header files in a directory that is included in the default search. The gcc default search goes to `/usr/include/` and wxwidgets adds `/wx-3.2-unofficial/wx/` into the include directory. So after spending hours of trying other suggestions, I got the gcc manual for the version installed on my system (ver 7.5.0) The manual states:

> **3.15 Options for Directory Search**
>
> These options specify directories to search for header files, for
> libraries and for parts of the compiler:
>
> - `-I dir`
> - `-iquote dir`
> - `-isystem dir`
> - `-idirafter dir`
>
> Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for
> header files during preprocessing.
>
> 3. Directories specified with ‘-I’ options are scanned in left-to-right order.
> 4. Directories specified with ‘-isystem’ options are scanned in left-to-right order.
> 5. Standard system directories are scanned.
> 6. Directories specified with ‘-idirafter’ options are scanned in left-to-right order.
>
> The ‘-isystem’ and ‘-idirafter’ options also mark the directory as a
> system directory, so that it gets the same special treatment that is
> applied to the standard system directories

So if I read this correctly, `gcc -isystem /dir`/  should specify the directory you want the system to search for files in. But it doesn't. All results are: "fatal error no input files. compilation terminated".

My attempts:

```
gcc -isystem /wx-3.2-unofficial/wx/
gcc -isystem /usr/include/wx-3.2-unofficial/wx/
gcc -I /wx-3.2-unofficial/wx/
gcc -I /usr/include/wx-3.2-unofficial/wx/
```

Comment: If the attempts you mention are literally the commands you tried, then indeed there is no actual source code file listed, and the error `no input files` makes perfect sense. Nothing wxWidgets-specific about that. Are you familiar with compiling a simple "Hello world" program with gcc on command line, without wxWidgets or any other additional libraries?

Comment: Actually, it makes no sense. There are no files for compilation, I am merely trying to add a pointer to a directory to access files.     "Directories specified with ‘-I’, ‘-isystem’, or ‘-idirafter’ apply to lookup for both the #include "file" and #include <file> directives."

Comment: @rob.bob.dave, do you use any IDE?

Comment: @rob.bob.dave It sounds like you have some misconception about how gcc works; you seem to be assuming it has some kind of internal configuration that you could permanently modify by giving it paths like that – but it doesn't. Giving it no input files is analogous to going to a counter at a store and declaring you want to pay by credit card, but having no items to buy with you.

Comment: Igor - Yes Genie IDE

Comment: ...why are you running `gcc` (and not `g++`) to compile C++ code?

Comment: Lauri Nurmi - According to the manual and what I've read from various solutions, yes, it is a modification to a configuration although nowhere does it indicate it is permanent... or not.

Comment: genpfault - did not know about g++ just trying to get it to find the necessary header files.

Comment: @rob.bob.dave, if you are on Linux/Mac, why not use `wx-config --cxxflags` option? If you are on Windows - just manually add the appropriate directory.

Comment: Igor - Thank you. It seems I usually chose the most difficult path through internet inquiries that lead me, um, the wrong way.